# SAS to create a GROUP ID

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following data

```
data have;
  input id seq value;
datalines;
1 1 4
1 2 4
1 3 0
1 4 0
1 5 0
1 6 4
1 7 4
2 1 1
2 2 1
2 3 5
2 4 5
2 5 5
2 6 8
;
run;
```

I need to create a groupid variable, which depends on the id and value, so that the output looks like this,

```
id seq value grpid
1   1    4     1
1   2    4     1
1   3    0     2
1   4    0     2
1   5    0     2
1   6    4     3
1   7    4     3
2   1    1     1
2   2    1     1
2   3    5     2
2   4    5     2
2   5    5     2
2   6    8     3
```

I have no idea how to achieve this, the error that I run into is this,

> ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set

But I cannot change the sorting, the dataset needs to be sorted by id and seq variables first before generating the grpid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
  input id seq value;
datalines;
1 1 4
1 2 4
1 3 0
1 4 0
1 5 0
1 6 4
1 7 4
2 1 1
2 2 1
2 3 5
2 4 5
2 5 5
2 6 8
;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   by id value notsorted;
   if first.id then grpid = 0;
   if first.value then grpid + 1;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterClemmensen this works. I didn't know about the not sorted option.

Answer (score 1):

The `BY` statement has option `NOTSORTED` to allow you to use `first.` and `last.` to process rows that are contiguous but otherwise disordered.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id value NOTSORTED;

  if first.id then grpid = 1;
  else 
  if first.value then grpid + 1;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard, much appreciated, I learnt something new today :)